# Auto remove uber cart product attributes's option

Tags: 7, ubercart

Module: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart

Scenario:
 
Product A: (has three options)
- blue (Expire in May) (It has node to describe more about this option)
- green (Expire in May) (It has node to describe more about this option)
- red (Expire in June) (It has node to describe more about this option)

Currently I use [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module to auto remove the node once its expire, but unable to remove product attributes's option. As a result, I use rule to send me email once node had been remove.

Question: Can I use rule to remove product attribute's option or is there any other solution?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Commerce Product Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) module. I haven't use this module. But I hope you will get that you want.

> This module provides some enhancements to the Drupal Commerce
>   attribute handling.
>
> The improvement contains:
>
> - Attribute field for line item
> - Edit option for attributes

**Or**

Try this [Refer Link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1311856) also if you will not getting any solution from above module.

**Or**

You can do this by adding below code to Ubercart Attribute module.

```
contributions/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.module, line 831
```

[uc_attribute_option_delete](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_attribute%21uc_attribute.module/function/uc_attribute_option_delete/7)

```
function uc_attribute_option_delete($oid) {
  // Delete the class attribute options.
  uc_attribute_subject_option_delete($oid, 'class');

  // Delete the product attribute options (and the adjustments!).
  uc_attribute_subject_option_delete($oid, 'product');

  // Delete base attributes and their options.
  db_delete('uc_attribute_options')
    ->condition('oid', $oid)
    ->execute();

  return SAVED_DELETED;
}
```

Comment: Thank for advice. I think Commerce Product is only works for default cart module. Not with ubercart. With your hint, I do a bit research and found this link: https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_product_as_attribute_option However, it only manage display stock......Now I trying to use option 2 method, but not really sure how. I only need to delete product's option and need to meet the condition.